# Error Ajax , Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i'm getting syntax error like this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

and this is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jk_id').on('change',function(){
        let id = $this.val();
        $('#kk_id').empty();
        $('#kk_id').append('<option value="0" selected disabled>--- Pilih Komponen Kegiatan ---</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'admin/pengajuan/create1/' + id,
            success: function(response) {
                var response = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response);
                $('#kk_id').empty();
                $('#kk_id').append('<option value="0" selected disabled>--- Pilih Komponen Kegiatan ---</option>');
                response.forEach(element => {
                    $('#kk_id').append('<option value ="${element['id']}">${element['name']}</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i'm new on Jquery............................................................................

Comment: Are you trying to use template literals on this 6th line up?

Comment: $this.val() needs to be wrapped in parentheses $(this).val()

Comment: @jhon Thanks for the corrections, but i got some troble after fix that things, igot new error  like this 
    VM15738:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (create:369)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
'<option value ="${element['id']}">${element['name']}</option>'
```

on the 6th line up with

```
`<option value ="${element['id']}">${element['name']}</option>`
```

Notice I used the grave accent ( ` ) character instead of single-quotes ( ' ) at the beggining and end. This will allow you to use template literals.

Comment: thanks that's solve the problem, now the different error is showing can you help me ?